# Awake app via BLE broadcast

Tags: ios, background, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am finding a contradictory information on this so I need help from iOS BLE expert.

Namely, there is a device that can detect when someone is jamming it. In that case, it will send a broadcast message and a warning will appear in iOS app. This works perfectly when the app is in the foreground. When I put it to the background by pressing the home button, it stops reacting to jamming broadcast messages.

So, is it possible that app received BLE message when it's in the background?

If it is not possible, what is the workable solution to solve this use case? Please propose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the background mode `bluetooth-central` in your app plist for the key `UIBackgroundModes`.

You can also do it via the Capabilities tab in your target properties, and set "Uses Bluetooth LE accessories" in Background Modes.

Comment: And the app will be able to receive jamming alert from the BLE device?

Comment: You will be able to explore, connect, receive data of your BLE device, yes ; Almost as if you were in foreground mode. There are a few limitations on scanning for new devices while in background.